# Is there an alternative for MYSQL HAVING

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, having

I'm trying to find some records based on the tags they have. In order to find out which tags a record has i add them to the result using a subquery. To find out which results should be returned i added a having statement on the end of the query. But something tells me this is not the best way.

```
SELECT e.id, e.title, e.text, e.introduction,
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(e.starts_on) AS starts_on,
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(e.ends_on) AS ends_on,
  m.id AS meta_id,
  m.url,
  cm.title AS category_title,
  cm.url AS category_url,
  CONCAT(
    ",",
    (
      SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.id)
      FROM modules_tags AS mt
      JOIN tags AS t ON t.id = mt.tag_id
      WHERE mt.other_id = e.id
    ),","
  ) AS tags_search
FROM event_posts AS e
INNER JOIN meta AS m ON e.meta_id = m.id
LEFT JOIN event_categories AS c ON e.category_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN meta AS cm ON c.meta_id = cm.id
LEFT JOIN modules_tags AS mt ON mt.other_id = e.id
LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON t.id = mt.tag_id
WHERE 1 HAVING tags_search LIKE '%,5,%' AND tags_search LIKE '%,6,%'
```

Comment: HAVING is unnecessary in this case. HAVING filters after GROUP BY, when WHERE filters before. So the WHERE clause would do the same thing in this case.

Comment: I haven't tested this so it may not work, but unless you need tags_search in your code later after the query, then you could put the filters you have in HAVING in the sub-query — but move that sub-query to the main query's WHERE clause with an EXISTS expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) is the best way to find values in comma separated values in MySQL.